# Corrupt pdf document with iText

Tags: android, adobe, itext

I am having some problems with android and iText if someone could help please.

The android app writes multiple pages, each containing different tables. Rather than allowing a table to cross over a page I add a table for each page and create a new table for the next page. That way I retain control over page totals and headers and footers.

The problem I have is that the Android adobe pdf reader display the document fine, exactly was I was looking for. However when I open a window on my pc to access the /mnt/sdcard folder on the tablet, where the file is created, and open the document with the Adobe reader on my pc, adobe reader X, the get a message saying
there was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired.

This is highly frustrating and I am certain the the correct number of columns are being added to the tables. I do use colspan and rowspan quite a bit. Not sure whether that has something to do with it. If I skip the main section of the document it seems to work fine.

Are there known issues with iText and Adobe X.

I don't finalise the tables at all, just use document.add(table), but I do close the document. doc.close().

I have also tried copying to my desktop but no difference

Thanks for any help

Pete

---

I have tried to re-open the document with iText PDFReader class and get the following error.

```
Rebuild failed: trailer not found.; Original message: PDF startxref not found.
```

After investigation it appears that the output stream maybe being closed too early, although why it should display in tablet I'm not sure. Maybe it concatenates the documents somehow. The stream is opened as shown

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(Const.PDF_PATH+FILE));
document.open();
document.addTitle("Pilot Flight Logbook");
document.addSubject("Log of all Flights");
document.addKeywords("Java, PDF, iText");
document.addAuthor("ProPilot");
document.addCreator("ProPilot");
```

Does this seem to be the correct track. If so how can I stop the stream closing automatically?

Comment: Please provide the pdf in question and the code, if possible, boiled down into a [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Sorry, not really possible. The source is too large for on here. Is there is a program somewhere to check what is wrong with the pdf ie why adobe is objecting to it.\n File is here  http://w2.peterbambrook.co.uk:8080/documents/ProPilot%20Logbook.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Compare the file size of the document on your tablet (you see it's too large for SO) to its file size when looking at it on your computer. The file you're sharing on your site is not a complete PDF. It looks as if it was cut in two at an arbitrary place. Maybe you didn't copy it completely or maybe there are some restrictions on the file size.

In any case: I opened your PDF in Notepad++ and scrolled to the end. Every PDF should end with `%%EOF`. Yours ends at an arbitrary place inside a stream object (stream objects normally end with the keyword `endstream`).

Once you find what causes your PDF to be truncated to 8,465 bytes, you've solved your problem. The culprit won't be iText if you say the PDF displays correctly on your tablet.

Comment: Bit of an update. It seems that if I shut the tablet down and re-start it, then open the document from the PC it works fine. So somehow when I use doc.close() it isn't actually flushing and finalising the document. Is there a way in Android to force the finalising of the file. That I suppose is why it works in the tables PDF reader, it gets the rest of the document from its memory buffers somehow. Any thoughts, help please.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error (iText7, Acrobat 11-generated fillable PDF) and the solution was to open the PDF in Acrobat Pro, run it through the Optimizer tool, strip unnecessary attributes, downgrade the file from PDF v1.7 to v1.5, remove compression.  Only then could Adobe Reader open the PDF after it was modified/stamped by iText7.

Answer (score 0):

To make certain that the streams are being managed correctly, you might want to try converting them to try with resources blocks. When you do it like that, they'll be automatically closed when you reach the end of your block, but will otherwise stay open until you manually close them. Something like this:

```
try (OutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(Const.PDF_PATH+FILE)) {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, oStream);
    document.open();
    document.addTitle("Pilot Flight Logbook");
    document.addSubject("Log of all Flights");
    document.addKeywords("Java, PDF, iText");
    document.addAuthor("ProPilot");
    document.addCreator("ProPilot");
    < DO MORE STUFF>
} // your stream will close here
```